# Book recommendations for biostatisticians in CRO and pharmacy

Tags: experiment-design, references, clinical-trials, reporting

I would like to learn more about the work and statistical methods performed as biostatistician in pharmaceutical companies and clinical research organizations.

It seems the book "Essential Medical Statistics" (Kirkwood et. al) seems useful. In another thread I saw "Clinical Trials: A Methodologic Perspective" (Piantadosi) advertised.

What are your opinions and views for suitable books?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must include the excellent "[Statistical Issues in Drug Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470018771)" by Stephen Senn. Brilliant book.

Comment: That is the type of book I am looking for. I think gung's suggestion is very interesting but more targeted at general career planning. If Michael Chernick or other experts in biostatistics have further key books this advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You might find Hahn, & Doganaksoy (2011). [*A Career in Statistics: Beyond the Numbers*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470404418), to be helpful for your purposes.

Comment: At first this seemed too generic but the book looks fascinating.